# Создание мультиплеерной игры c сервером на Asp.Net Core + SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, rabbitmq, signalr

Разрабатываю онлайн игру в которой 8 игроков объединяются в отдельные комнаты.

Идея в том, что игроку дается определенное время на совершенние каких-либо действий, доступных ему в определенной фазе игры. Фазы меняются спустя некоторое время либо при совершении игроком действий. После прохождения всех фаз ход переходит другому игроку и все фазы повторяются.

Клиент с помощью signalR вызывает единственный метод на хабе, который принимает имя ивента и параметры этого ивента, который необходимо обработать на сервере. С помощью рефлексии создается объект хендлера, соответствующего ивенту, после чего вызывается метод, обрабатывающий ивент.
Есть идея, все ивенты каждой комнаты объединить в очереди, после чего обрабатывать их отдельно. Исходя из этого наткнулся на мысль, что под каждую команту нужно создавать какой-то бэкграунд сервис либо отдельные мини сервера.

Хотелось бы узнать есть ли какие-то решения, как это организовать, учитывая тот факт, что данные сервисы должны работать параллельно.
Также хотелось бы узнать о производительности и целесообразности данного подхода.
Также при разработке хотелось бы учитывать:

1. Скорость обмена сообщениями между игроками и сервером.
2. Нагрузка на сервер при большом трафике запросов.
3. Найти оптимальное решение, которое при масштабируемости сервера не повлечет слишком сильных расходов.

Updates: Я нашел временное решение, я создаю бесконечные задачи, используя DataFlow library. Теперь, когда игрок присоединяется к комнате, я начинаю новую игру и создаю новую бесконечную задачу. Однако возникает проблема в том, что мне нужно где-то хранить задачи и повторно подключив пользователя к комнате, прикрепить его к правильной задаче. Есть ли способ сделать это?

Также теперь У меня есть один концентратор с 2 методами:

1. JointPlayerToRoom(где я создаю новую игру)
2. SendEvent (где я отправляю событие в очередь redis, а затем обрабатываю это событие в созданной задаче, задача тоже работает с очередью).

Comment: Привет, знаю как сделать микросервисы (WEB-API) в ASP.NET Core, как организовать Очереди в RabbitMQ и подружить их с  ASP.NET Core, но не знаю SignalR. Поэтому, с интересом посмотрю на предложенное полноценное решение, для такой задачи.

Comment: @AndreiBrizhak Привет, очереди начал делать через Redis, но столкнулся с проблемой, что либа что я использую, не позволяет сделать приоритетную очередь(использую StackExchange.Redis). Скорее всего буду переходить на rabbitmq или искать более производительные решения, т.к скорость очень важна для данного типа проекта. Насчет задачи, описанной выше, в данный момент работаю над решением моей проблемы, как только что-то надумаю, обновлю вопрос)

Comment: Вот рабочий код в [репозитории](https://github.com/AndyBrizhak/Mango), с детальными комитами, где используется на .NET 6,  ASP.NET Core MVC+WEB-API+RabbitMQ, может быть будет интересно.